# Magento 2.3. changing form validation options loses validation messages translations

Tags: magento2.3, form-validation, translate, js-translation

I am running **Magento 2.3**. In the customer create account form I changed the way validation form errors are shown in this way:

```
var dataForm = $('#form-validate');

dataForm.mage('validation', {
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        ... custom functionality ...
    }
}
```

Doing this all the validation messages lose their translations and are shown in English. If I comment out this piece of code the messages are shown in the current store language.

Anyone had this behaviour before?